# Azure SDK for Java - sample program throwing InvalidKeyException

Tags: java, azure, azure-table-storage

Using Azure Storage SDK for Java, I am trying to perform basic create, read, update, delete operations on Azure Table Storage as given in the link below:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-table-storage/

Sample program for creating a table:

```
package com.azure.test;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.CloudTable;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.CloudTableClient;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.utils.Base64;

public class App 
{

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws StorageException,    UnsupportedEncodingException
{

    String storageConnectionString =
            "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;" +
            "AccountName=accountname;" + 
            "AccountKey=storagekey;"+
           "EndpointSuffix=table.core.windows.net"; 

    try
    {
        // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
           CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

        CloudTableClient tableClient =               storageAccount.createCloudTableClient();

      //Create the table if it doesn't exist.
       String tableName = "MyTable";
       CloudTable cloudTable = tableClient.getTableReference(tableName);
       cloudTable.createIfNotExists();               

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Output the stack trace.
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The code seems to be fairly simple to understand. It would connect to the Azure table storage and if a table with a given name does not exist it will create it. But I am getting a InvalidKeyException(full exception pasted below).

> java.security.InvalidKeyException: Storage Key is not a valid base64 encoded string.
>       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageCredentials.tryParseCredentials(StorageCredentials.java:68)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.CloudStorageAccount.tryConfigureServiceAccount(CloudStorageAccount.java:408)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.CloudStorageAccount.parse(CloudStorageAccount.java:259)
>       at com.azure.test.App.main(App.java:71)

I am surprised that not many people using Azure Storage are facing this issue. I tried to encode the storage key using and used the encoded key in the connection string but still no use.

```
String encodedKey=Base64.encode(storageKey.getBytes())

String storageConnectionString =
            "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;" +
            "AccountName=accountname" + 
            "AccountKey="+encodedKey+
           "EndpointSuffix=table.core.windows.net;";
```

Can anyone please help me with this? I searched in google a lot and I am able to find one user raised a similar issue on discus but there is no answer provided for that or rather that answer was not helpful.

Comment: Hello Brian, I took your suggestion and posted my solution in the answer box. Also, I am trying to upvote Gaurav's answer which did help me a bit but I am not able to because of my low number of reps. We need at least 15 reps for our upvotes to count unfortunately.

Comment: You should be able to accept one the of the answers by clicking on the tick, even if you can't vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the following line of code:

```
String storageConnectionString =
            "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;" +
            "AccountName=accountname" + 
            "AccountKey="+encodedKey+
           "EndpointSuffix=table.core.windows.net;";
```

To

```
String storageConnectionString =
            "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;" +
            "AccountName=accountname" + 
            ";AccountKey="+encodedKey+
           ";EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;";
```

Essentially in your code, there was no separator (`;`) between `AccountName`, `AccountKey` and `EndpointSuffix`. Also, if you're connecting to standard endpoint (`core.windows.net`), you don't need to specify `EndpointSuffix` in your connection string.

Lastly, please ensure that the account key is correct.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, thank you for the quick reply. I did separate the AccountName, AccountKey and EndpointSuffix parameters in my actual code but for the sake of privacy I edited the connection string to remove my actual AccountName and Accountkey when I posted here and along with them I removed the semicolon separators by mistake. When I ran my sample program the separators were there at the relevant places but still my program threw this exception. About the EndpointSuffix, I did not give it when I ran my sample for the first time. It threw a StorageException caused by an UnknownHost Exception.

Comment: Using same credentials I am able to connect to my azure table storage using the Azure Storage Explorer tool. So the credentials are valid. Also I edited my question to include the separators in the connection string. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please update your question with the exact code you're using. Please replace the account name and key with some dummy values. It is actually quite hard to say what's wrong with your code without actually seeing the actual code you're using.

Comment: I just included the dummy values for AccountName and AccountKey. The rest of the code is exactly the same, Gaurav.

Comment: Can you try by removing "EndpointSuffix=table.core.windows.net" from your 1st connection string?

Comment: Hi Gaurav, I already tried that and I am getting a StorageException caused by UnknownHostException.. Since I am away from my work machine now, I am unable to post the entire Stacktrace now.. will post it tomorrow.. thanks for your quick replies

Comment: I programmatically set the proxy settings through the system properties and it solved the issue for me. Thanks for your help Gaurav.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:/Resolution of the issue**

First of all I ensured that all the properties in connection string are separated by ';' as suggested by Gaurav(below)

It turns out that I have to manually set the proxy settings in my program since my company work machine is using a proxy to connect to the internet.

```
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "myproxyHost");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "myProxyPort");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyUser", "myProxyUser");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPassword","myProxyPassword");
```

Updating the proxy settings solved the issue for me.